# How the log from SRCDS can be received in node.js

Tags: node.js

My question is similar to the question: [How to recieve log from SRCDS in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919790/how-to-recieve-log-from-srcds-in-node-js), but the problem is that the solution represented in the link above does not solve my problem.

So, I have SRCDS (Source Dedicated Server) which runs cs:go instance and NodeJS running.

To send logs to NodeJS, I add to the console of SRCDS:

```
log on
logaddress_add myAddress:myPort
```

In this case, `myAddress:myPort` is `127.0.0.1:8006`.

To catch with NodeJS the sent logs, I am using the following piece of the code:

```
var dgram = require('dgram'),
server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');



server.on('message', function (message, rinfo) {
var msg = message.toString('ascii').slice(5,-1);    
console.log(msg);
    });


server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});

server.bind({
  address: 'localhost',
  port: 8006,
  exclusive: true
});
```

The problem is that this approach perfectly works with CS (Counter-Strike) 1.6.

Even when I am trying to send logs (by typing `log on` and `logaddress_add myAddress:myPort` (in this case `127.0.0.1:8006`)) from local server (not SRCDS) it does not work.

Comment: Could you describe `it does not work`? Does nothing happen? Can you confirm srcds is actually sending log packets? Are you behind a router (or, is srcds on the same subnet as your server)? What does your output look like?

Comment: Generally, nothing happens. I can not confirm that the logs from srcds are sent (I was thinking about it and I do not know how to test it), but I can confirm that they are written. I am in the same subnet as my server, so I do not think that I am behind my router.

Output example:
L 11/18/2015 - 00:01:17: "Chet<2><BOT><>" connected, address ""
L 11/18/2015 - 00:01:17: "Chet<2><BOT>" switched from team <Unassigned> to <TERR
ORIST>
L 11/18/2015 - 00:01:17: World triggered "Game_Commencing"
L 11/18/2015 - 00:01:17: "Chet<2><BOT><>" entered the game

Comment: can you use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to confirm they're being sent? the filter `udp && udp.port == 8006` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Qix marking your comment as a useful one, sorry for the late reaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem was solved by my colleague.

It seems that cs:go server does not send the data to localhost. So, server binding has to be changed.

Thus, a public server has to be added (server.addMembership('224.0.0.114')).

Then the log forwarding from the server has to be set to the ip-address specified below:
***"logaddress_add 224.0.0.144:1234"***

Here is a correct code:

```
var dgram = require('dgram'),
    server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('message', function (message, rinfo) {
var msg = message.toString('ascii').slice(5,-1);    
console.log(msg);
    });


server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});

server.bind(1234, function() {
  server.addMembership('224.0.0.114');
});
```

It perfectly works with a local server. So, no need to start SRCDS.

Qix, thanks for the help.

D.